# Pandas Filter with condition reocrds is reduced

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame with 175759 records. There is a column 'os' which indicate only "Windows" or "Linux".

I want to create a data frame with condition if `os` is Windows only. Manually filter `"os" = " Windows` shows that I should have 161,978 records but when I use pandas to create the data frame, I only have 17,320 records. The code I used is as below.

```
os_windows = df_all[df_all.os == 'Windows']
```

Is there another way to filter rows with condition? Or what was wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Look at `df_all.os.value_counts()`. What do you see?

Comment: Wow!! Dataframe window has small caps "w" but excel convert all to caps! Thanks ALollz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your column values contains leading and trailing spaces. Try this

```
df_all['os'] = df_all['os'].str.strip()
os_windows = df_all[df_all.os == 'Windows']
```

or

```
df_all['os'] = df_all['os'].str.strip()
os_windows = df_all[df_all['os'] == 'Windows']
```

also Try this as well

```
os_windows = df_all[df_all['os'].str.contains('Windows')]
```